# CSS breaking on HTML Table to email using PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, email

Below is my code for sending email

```
 $to = 'kavya@techryte.com';
$subject = "Edufly Global Studies";

$message = file_get_contents("email_template.html");
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <prashob@eduflyglobal.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

AND in file email_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>[SUBJECT]</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body style="padding: 15px 100px 15px 100px">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<h1>TAT time for stages</h1>
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
<tr>
  <th>From Stage</th>
  <th>To Stage</th>
  <th>TAT Time</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Telecounselling</td>
<td>Counselling</td>
<td>25 days</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Counselling</td>
<td>Documentation</td>
<td>7 days</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Documentation</td>
<td>Offer Application</td>
<td>2 days</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Offer Application</td>
<td>Offer Received (New)</td>
<td>30 days</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Offer Received</td>
<td>Visa Applied</td>
<td>25 days</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Visa Applied</td>
<td>Visa Received (New)</td>
<td>20 days</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Visa Received</td>
<td>Payment</td>
<td>60 days</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </html>
```

If I run html code alone its formatted in bootstrap table like below screenshot

[image]

But in mail I receive like unformatted table

[image]

What Mistake I made with this.Please anyone Help me to get out of this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obvioulsy your css files from cdns are ignored. Use inline styles.

Comment: while sending emails use inline css. Try looking for email templates.

Comment: I tried with inline css too.Now also I got unformatted table to my email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `message` parameter to send your `mail` body of the content like this,

```
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['req-name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Type of Change:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['typeOfChange']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Urgency:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['urgency']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>URL To Change (main):</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['URL-main'] . "</td></tr>";
$addURLS = $_POST['addURLS'];
if (($addURLS) != '') {
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>URL To Change (additional):</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($addURLS) . "</td></tr>";
}
$curText = htmlentities($_POST['curText']);           
if (($curText) != '') {
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>CURRENT Content:</strong> </td><td>" . $curText . "</td></tr>";
}
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>NEW Content:</strong> </td><td>" . htmlentities($_POST['newText']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Even this how can add bootstrap table with this content

Comment: i think its just a table just write your own css better @KavyaShree

Comment: Okie ill try in that way

Comment: okay final test, you try to send this ID `kavya@techryte.com` right plz try with some other service provider like `gmail` `yahoo` `apple` IDs. bcz some server not accept. try with gmail. 1.inline and 2.message parameter. then come back @Kavya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128354/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-karthi).

Answer (score 0):

When you are open template it shows with correct formfitting because bootstrap is already loaded on your browser (here bootstrap makes the formatting)

But open it from your email it showing without formatting because bootstrap is not there and that is obvious thing.

So If you need have well formatted template, you should apply inline CSS on your template itself (I mean there should not be any css files included )

Comment: Then I can download bootstrap css and store in local css file right